# Isn't the derivative of internal energy with respect to volume with constant temperature in the isobaric heat capacity zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

The formula for the isobaric heat capacity is
$$C_p = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V + \left[\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T+p\right]\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p.$$
Isn't the term
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T$$
supposed to be zero, as it describes a process with no change in temperature, thus the change in internal energy is
$$\Delta U = C_V\Delta T=0,$$
or, alternatively, it describes isothermic process (or at least the isothermic part of isobaric process), where all of the heat supplied to a system is changed into work and no energy is left over to change internal energy?

Comment: Only so if the internal energy depends on temperature alone. The formula for the caloric equation $U=U(\cdot, \cdot, ..)$ where the dots represent thermodynamic variables. This is a constitutive relationship not a law, just as "$F=-kx$" *defines* an ideal spring, a perfect gas  is defined by the pair of constitutive equations $pV=mRT$ and $U=U(T)$. Here you have 5 variables, $p,V,m,T,U$, and thermodynamics supplies further differential relationships among these.

Comment: @hyportnex The derivation of the isobaric heat capacity I found relies on the fact that $U=U(T,V)$ only. It is constructed by finding the differential of a multivariable function (of variables T,V), so, if it contained more variables, then the heat capacity would also contain derivatives of internal energy with respect to said variables.

Comment: Exactly, it is *assumed* that $U=U(T,V)$ which is right at the start a *special* case because in general $U$ should also depend on the amount of *mass*. Think of a large gaseous mass, you do know that there must be some gravitational effect holding it together in addition to its T and V, etc. For a small amount of gas you may neglect $m$ and we do most of the time but that is a constitutive assumption on the stuff not a *general* thermodynamic law just as Ohm's law describes *some* resistors in a linear relationship between current and voltage, but it is clearly wrong for a $pn$ diode.

Comment: Internal energy depends only on temperature in the case of an ideal gas.